# Custom types either not working in compiler or VSCode intellisense

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, intellisense

I have an express TS app for which I wrote a custom middleware which adds properties to req object. I tried looking at ways by which I can extend the type or redefine it and I found that I can use `types.d.ts` file, which looks like this for me:

```js
import Express from 'express'
import { JwtPayload } from 'jsonwebtoken'
export {}

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      locals: {
        someBoolProperty: boolean
        someOtherProperty: string
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    // Process & infer types from .js files.
    "allowJs": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "declaration": true,
    // Enable strictest settings like strictNullChecks & noImplicitAny.
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,

    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    // Search under node_modules for non-relative imports.
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    // Import non-ES modules as default imports.
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "incremental": true,
  },
  "files": ["./types.d.ts"]
}
```

This works well for the compiler, but my VSCode intellisense keeps underlining the `locals` property on request object. When I remove `files` property from `tsconfig.json`, suddenly my  VSCode intellisense works like a charm, but the compiler now throws an error about the property not existing on request object.

I am not sure whether I have misconfigured anything in my tsconfig or whether there is some other problem.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that I also tried adding this `/// <reference path="../../types.d.ts" />` to my file using this extended Request type, but since I will have to use this `locals` property in multiple routers, I would love to find a less cumbersome and simply a better alternative.

Typescript version 4.8.4
Node version 16.17.1

Comment: Three questions for you (just numbered for convenience): 1. What happens if you change [`files`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#files) to [`includes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include)? 2. Where is `types.d.ts` file relative to the TypeScript source code where you're trying to use `locals`? 3. Where is `types.d.ts` relative to the `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder when I change it to `include`, compiler doesn't work anymore, but VSCode intellisense starts working.
`types.d.ts` is in root, file with `locals` is located in /src/utils/middleware.ts file
`tsconfig.json` is also in root

Comment: I missclicked on enter when trying to add a new line, not realizing that it posts a comment directly, whoopsie x)

Comment: The fact that the Question/Answer box and the comment boxes behave *so* differently is one of the many issues with the SE system that they'll never get around to fixing. :-|

Comment: I also added an edit to the original post with a clarification about what worked but I did not find it to be a sustainable solution :/